# javascript Создание файлов стороне клиента или на стороне сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

Есть редактор статей (типа блога), хочу сделать создание некого "черновика", например, если пользователь, не дописав статью, закрыл вкладку и других случаев.
Я хотел бы хранить эти файлы черновиков на сервере в папочке, но не знаю, где лучше и безопаснее сделать создание этих файлов, на клиенте или на сервере. Я попытался сделать на клиенте с помощью обращения к модулю node js, но получил ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Editor.js**

```
import {writeFile} from './fs.js';

...

const CreateDraft = () => {
    WriteToFile();
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + h + ':' + m;
    fs.writeFile(`{today}.json`, '', function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log('error', err);
        else return `{today}.json`;
    });

    fs.writeFile({name: 'foo.txt', data: 'barbarbar'})

    return ``;
}
```

**Server.js**

```
app.get('/fs.js', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Редирект в node_modules');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/fs-es6/index.js');
    console.log(__dirname);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На клиенте (если под клиентом имеется в виду браузер) используйте localStorage или IndexDB. На сервере - как обычно любой backend (я так в понимаю в Вашем случае nodejs), на который "черновики" передаются как обычно POST|PUT|PATCH.